# Possibly lossy conversion from long to int

Tags: java, exception

I am getting "incompatible types: possibly loss of conversion from long to int" exception in this line: boolean arr[] = new boolean [limit]; I don't understand why this is happening since I am storing the input value in long, how is it getting converted to int?

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;
 public class PrimeSieve
{
public static void main (String args [])
{
   //getting the number
   Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("What is your number?");
   long limit = x.nextLong();
   long count = 0;

   //making all the numbers upto the given number prime
   boolean arr[] = new boolean [limit]; 
   for ( long i = 2; i <=Math.sqrt(limit); i++) 
   {
       arr[i] = true;
   }
```

Comment: Even if you could do it, do you realize how much RAM this would consume?  Maybe an array is simply not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This because you are using a `long` as a size for an array.

Java supports array up to a certain limit which is around `Integer.MAX_VALUE - x` (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays)) so using a long to specify the size is not allowed.

Quoting from JLS:

> Arrays must be indexed by int values... An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error.

Comment: Then how do I store my desired number in the array? If I am changing the long to int, i am getting a java.util.mismatch exception. I read similar problems and found that I maybe able to use 2D arrays or ArrayList but I am fairly new to java so I am not sure how to

Answer (score 0):

Array lengths and indices must always be `int`s.  You cannot create an array with `long` length, nor can you refer to a `long` index in an array.

Comment: but what if the input exceeds the limits of ints? like if the input is something like 123456789101112, then I am getting a java.util.mismatch exception

Comment: Then you can't use an array.  You'll have to use some other data structure or algorithm.